# General error: 1366 Incorrect string value in Laravel/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email, laravel-5, php-imap

I have designed laravel app to fetch mails using php imap.
In kernel I have written code to fetch all mailboxes, below is my code for fetching mails from mailbox

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Email;
use App\Models\Inbox;
use App\Models\Spam;
use App\Models\Sent;
use App\Models\Drafts;
use App\Models\Trash;
use App\Models\Junk;
use App\Models\Attachments;
use App\Models\Errorlogs;

use PhpImap\Mailbox as ImapMailbox;
use PhpImap\IncomingMail;
use PhpImap\IncomingMailAttachment;


class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{

    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    public function saveMail($result,$mailboxType,$mailbox,$stream,$j,$accountId,$appUrl)
    {

        $i=0;
        while(1)
        {
            try
            {
                if(isset($result[$i]))    
                {
                    $mail=$mailbox->getMail($result[$i],false);

                    $status = imap_headerinfo($stream,$j);
                    $status = ( $status->Unseen == 'U') ? 'unread' : 'read';

                    if($mailboxType=="Inbox")
                        $mbVar = new Inbox;
                    elseif($mailboxType=="Sent")
                        $mbVar = new Sent;
                    elseif($mailboxType=="Spam")
                        $mbVar = new Spam;
                    elseif($mailboxType=="Drafts")
                        $mbVar = new Drafts;
                    elseif($mailboxType=="Trash")
                        $mbVar = new Trash;
                    elseif($mailboxType=="Junk")
                        $mbVar = new Junk;

                    $mbVar->accountId = $accountId;
                    $mbVar->flag = 'NULL';
                    $mbVar->mailId = $mail->id;
                    $mbVar->date = $mail->date;
                    $mbVar->subject = $mail->subject;
                    $mbVar->fromName = $mail->fromName;
                    $mbVar->fromAddress = $mail->fromAddress;
                    $mbVar->to = implode(",",$mail->to);
                    $mbVar->cc = implode(",",$mail->cc);
                    $mbVar->replyTo = implode(",",$mail->replyTo);
                    $mbVar->textPlain = $mail->textPlain;
                    $mbVar->textHtml = $mail->textHtml;
                    $mbVar->status = $status;
                    $mbVar->save();

                    $attachments = $mail->getAttachments();

                    if($attachments!=NULL)
                    {
                        foreach($attachments as $attachmentData)
                        {

                            if(!is_numeric($attachmentData->id))
                                break;

                            $attachment = new Attachments;
                            $attachment->mailId = $mbVar->id;
                            $attachment->mailboxType = $mailboxType;
                            $attachment->attachmentId = $attachmentData->id;
                            $attachment->fileName = $attachmentData->name;
                            $attachment->filePath = $appUrl."/storage/mail-attachments/".basename($attachmentData->filePath);

                            $attachment->save();
                        }

                    }

                    $i++;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            catch(\Exception $err)
            {
                $errorLog = new Errorlogs;
                $errorLog->errormsg = $err->getMessage();
                $errorLog->save();

            }
        }

    }
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function (Request $request) 
        {

            $mailBox=Email::get();
            foreach ($mailBox as $data) 
            {
                try
                {
                    $mbox = imap_open("{saniservice.com:993/imap/ssl}", $data->email,$data->password, OP_HALFOPEN)
                    or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

                    $list = imap_getmailboxes($mbox, "{saniservice.com:993/imap/ssl}", "*");

                    $j=1;
                    if(is_array($list)) 
                    {
                        foreach ($list as $key => $val) 
                        {
                            $mailbox = new ImapMailbox($val->name,$data->email,$data->password,storage_path().'/mail-attachments');
                            $mailIds = $mailbox->searchMailbox('ALL');
                            $stream = imap_open($val->name, $data->email,$data->password);

                            if($val->name=="{saniservice.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX")
                            {
                                $dbmailIds=Inbox::where('accountId',$data->id)->pluck('mailId')->toArray();
                                $result=array_values(array_diff($mailIds,$dbmailIds));

                                $this->saveMail($result,'Inbox',$mailbox,$stream,$j,$data->id,$request->url());

                            }
                            elseif ($val->name=="{saniservice.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.spam") 
                            {
                                $dbmailIds=Spam::where('accountId',$data->id)->pluck('mailId')->toArray();
                                $result=array_values(array_diff($mailIds,$dbmailIds));

                                $this->saveMail($result,'Spam',$mailbox,$stream,$j,$data->id,$request->url());

                            }
                            elseif ($val->name=="{saniservice.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Drafts") 
                            {
                                $dbmailIds=Drafts::where('accountId',$data->id)->pluck('mailId')->toArray();
                                $result=array_values(array_diff($mailIds,$dbmailIds));

                                $this->saveMail($result,'Drafts',$mailbox,$stream,$j,$data->id,$request->url());

                            }
                            elseif ($val->name=="{saniservice.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Sent") 
                            {
                                $dbmailIds=Sent::where('accountId',$data->id)->pluck('mailId')->toArray();
                                $result=array_values(array_diff($mailIds,$dbmailIds));

                                $this->saveMail($result,'Sent',$mailbox,$stream,$j,$data->id,$request->url());

                            }
                            elseif ($val->name=="{saniservice.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Junk") 
                            {
                                $dbmailIds=Junk::where('accountId',$data->id)->pluck('mailId')->toArray();
                                $result=array_values(array_diff($mailIds,$dbmailIds));

                                $this->saveMail($result,'Junk',$mailbox,$stream,$j,$data->id,$request->url());

                            }
                            elseif ($val->name=="{saniservice.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX.Trash") 
                            {
                                $dbmailIds=Trash::where('accountId',$data->id)->pluck('mailId')->toArray();
                                $result=array_values(array_diff($mailIds,$dbmailIds));

                                $this->saveMail($result,'Trash',$mailbox,$stream,$j,$data->id,$request->url());

                            }

                        }

                    }
                    imap_close($mbox);
                }
                catch(\Exception $e)
                {
                    $errorLog = new Errorlogs;
                    $errorLog->errormsg = $e->getMessage();
                    $errorLog->save();
                }
            }



        })->everyMinute()->name('mailfetch')->withoutOverlapping();
    }


    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

I have several email id's and password stored in table, the above code will loop (say outer loop) and it will fetch each mail credential , will connect to webmail and get all list of folders i.e inbox/sent/spam/trash/drafts/junk etc

Now for each folder say for inbox, it will again loop (say inner loop) and will fetch all mails that aren't in table already.

If I don't use try catch and any error occurs the complete process halts, that's why I used try catch for both inner and outer loop.

Now if I execute code and if fetched mail has no error then it will be added to appropriate table and if there is an error then it will be added to errorlog table.

**for some mails I am getting error message like this**

```
[PDOException] 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xA0|\xA0 Up. 
..' for column 'errormsg' at row 1
```

**ErrorLog Table Structure**
[image]

**Mysql Version is : 5.7.18**

This shows that there is no support for the data , that I am trying to add into table .

but I see that collation is fine and I have also used longtext to store the content.

I have searched for solution on this on internet but mostly solution is answered 7-8 years back, and I think my sql version has changed a lot from the time and none fo that worked for me

I am also not sure whether, should I change longtext datatype to LongBlob.

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException] 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xA0|\xA0 Up. 
..' for column 'errormsg' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `errorlogs` (`errormsg 
`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 
Incorrect string value: '\xA0|\xA0 Up...' for column 'errormsg' at row 1 ( 
SQL: insert into `errorlogs` (`errormsg`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) value 
s (SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xA0|\xA0 
Up...' for column 'textPlain' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `inbox` (`accountI 
d`, `flag`, `mailId`, `date`, `subject`, `fromName`, `fromAddress`, `to`, ` 
cc`, `replyTo`, `textPlain`, `textHtml`, `status`, `updated_at`, `created_a 
t`) values (3, NULL, 1678, 2013-03-20 00:03:08, DHL delivery report, Cruz D 
aniels, readjusting27@gmail.com, , , Cruz Daniels, /* Mobile-specific Style 
s */@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) { table[class=w0], td[ 
class=w0] { width: 0 !important; }table[class=w10], td[class=w10], img[clas 
s=w10] { width:10px !important; }table[class=w15], td[class=w15], img[class 
=w15] { width:5px !important; }table[class=w30], td[class=w30], img[class=w 
30] { width:10px !important; }table[class=w60], td[class=w60], img[class=w6 
0] { width:10px !important; }table[class=w125], td[class=w125], img[class=w 
125] { width:80px !important; }table[class=w130], td[class=w130], img[class 
=w130] { width:55px !important; }table[class=w140], td[class=w140], img[cla 
ss=w140] { width:90px !important; }table[class=w160], td[class=w160], img[c 
lass=w160] { width:180px !important; }table[class=w170], td[class=w170], im 
g[class=w170] { width:100px !important; }table[class=w180], td[class=w180], 
img[class=w180] { width:80px !important; }table[class=w195], td[class=w195 
], img[class=w195] { width:80px !important; }table[class=w220], td[class=w2 
20], img[class=w220] { width:80px !important; }table[class=w240], td[class= 
w240], img[class=w240] { width:180px !important; }table[class=w255], td[cla 
ss=w255], img[class=w255] { width:185px !important; }table[class=w275], td[ 
class=w275], img[class=w275] { width:135px !important; }table[class=w280], 
td[class=w280], img[class=w280] { width:135px !important; }table[class=w300 
], td[class=w300], img[class=w300] { width:140px !important; }table[class=w 
325], td[class=w325], img[class=w325] { width:95px !important; }table[class 
=w360], td[class=w360], img[class=w360] { width:140px !important; }table[cl 
ass=w410], td[class=w410], img[class=w410] { width:180px !important; }table 
[class=w470], td[class=w470], img[class=w470] { width:200px !important; }ta 
ble[class=w580], td[class=w580], img[class=w580] { width:280px !important; 
}table[class=w640], td[class=w640], img[class=w640] { width:300px !importan 
t; }table[class*=hide], td[class*=hide], img[class*=hide], p[class*=hide], 
span[class*=hide] { display:none !important; }table[class=h0], td[class=h0] 
{ height: 0 !important; }p[class=footer-content-left] { text-align: center 
!important; }#headline p { font-size: 30px !important; }.article-content, 
#left-sidebar{ -webkit-text-size-adjust: 90% !important; -ms-text-size-adju 
st: 90% !important; }.header-content, .footer-content-left {-webkit-text-si 
ze-adjust: 80% !important; -ms-text-size-adjust: 80% !important;}img { heig 
ht: auto; line-height: 100%;} } /* Client-specific Styles */#outlook a { pa 
dding: 0; } /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" button. */body 
{ width: 100% !important; }.ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }.ExternalClass { wi 
dth: 100%; display:block !important; } /* Force Hotmail to display emails a 
t full width *//* Reset Styles *//* Add 100px so mobile switch bar doesn't 
cover street address. */body { background-color: #dedede; margin: 0; paddin 
g: 0; }img { outline: none; text-decoration: none; display: block;}br, stro 
ng br, b br, em br, i br { line-height:100%; }h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { line 
-height: 100% !important; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }h1 a, h2 a, 
h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a { color: blue !important; }h1 a:active, h2 a:active 
, h3 a:active, h4 a:active, h5 a:active, h6 a:active {  color: red !importa 
nt; }/* Preferably not the same color as the normal header link color. The 
re is limited support for psuedo classes in email clients, this was added j 
ust for good measure. */h1 a:visited, h2 a:visited, h3 a:visited, h4 a:vis 
ited, h5 a:visited, h6 a:visited { color: purple !important; }/* Preferably 
not the same color as the normal header link color. There is limited suppo 
rt for psuedo classes in email clients, this was added just for good measur 
e. */ table td, table tr { border-collapse: collapse; }.yshortcuts, .yshor 
tcuts a, .yshortcuts a:link,.yshortcuts a:visited, .yshortcuts a:hover, .ys 
hortcuts a span {color: black; text-decoration: none !important; border-bot 
tom: none !important; background: none !important;} /* Body text color for 
the New Yahoo. This example sets the font of Yahoo's Shortcuts to black. * 
//* This most probably won't work in all email clients. Don't include bloc 
ks in email. */code { white-space: normal; word-break: break-all;}#backgr 
ound-table { background-color: #dedede; }/* Webkit Elements */#top-bar { bo 
rder-radius:6px 6px 0px 0px; -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px; -webkit-b 
order-radius:6px 6px 0px 0px; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; backgrou 
nd-color: #c7c7c7; color: #ededed; }#top-bar a { font-weight: bold; color: 
#ffffff; text-decoration: none;}#footer { border-radius:0px 0px 6px 6px; -m 
oz-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px; -webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 6px 6px; - 
webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }/* Fonts and Content */body, td { font 
-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif; }.header-c 
ontent, .footer-content-left, .footer-content-right { -webkit-text-size-adj 
ust: none; -ms-text-size-adjust: none; }/* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobil 
e platforms from changing default font sizes on header and footer. */.heade 
r-content { font-size: 12px; color: #ededed; }.header-content a { font-weig 
ht: bold; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; }#headline p { color: #444 
444; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif; f 
ont-size: 36px; text-align: center; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:30px; }#h 
eadline p a { color: #444444; text-decoration: none; }.article-title { font 
-size: 18px; line-height:24px; color: #b0b0b0; font-weight:bold; margin-top 
:0px; margin-bottom:18px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, 
Geneva, sans-serif; }.article-title a { color: #b0b0b0; text-decoration: no 
ne; }.article-title.with-meta {margin-bottom: 0;}.article-meta { font-size: 
13px; line-height: 20px; color: #ccc; font-weight: bold; margin-top: 0;}.a 
rticle-content { font-size: 13px; line-height: 18px; color: #444444; margin 
-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 18px; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helve 
tica, Geneva, sans-serif; }.article-content a { color: #2f82de; font-weight 
:bold; text-decoration:none; }.article-content img { max-width: 100% }.arti 
cle-content ol, .article-content ul { margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:18px; m 
argin-left:19px; padding:0; }.article-content li { font-size: 13px; line-he 
ight: 18px; color: #444444; }.article-content li a { color: #2f82de; text-d 
ecoration:underline; }.article-content p {margin-bottom: 15px;}.footer-cont 
ent-left { font-size: 12px; line-height: 15px; color: #ededed; margin-top: 
0px; margin-bottom: 15px; }.footer-content-left a { color: #ffffff; font-we 
ight: bold; text-decoration: none; }.footer-content-right { font-size: 11px 
; line-height: 16px; color: #ededed; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; 
}.footer-content-right a { color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; text-decorati 
on: none; }#footer { background-color: #c7c7c7; color: #ededed; }#footer a 
{ color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; }#permission-re 
minder { white-space: normal; }#street-address { color: #b0b0b0; white-spac 
e: normal; }.article-content ol, .article-content ul { margin: 0 0 0 24px 
; padding: 0; list-style-position: inside;} 


Web Version ?|? Update preferences??|? Unsubscribe 











DHL notification 

Our company?s courier couldn?t make the delivery of 
parcel. REASON: Postal code contai 
ns an error. LOCATION OF YOUR PA 
RCEL: New York DELIVERY STATUS: 
sort order SERVICE: One-day Ship 
ping NUMBER OF YOUR PARCEL: ETBA 
KPRSU3 FEATURES: No 
Label is enclosed to the letter. 
Print a label and show it at your post office 
. An additional information: 
If the parcel isn?t received within 15 
working days our company will have the right to claim compensation from you 
for it?s keeping in the amount of $8.26 for each day of keeping of it. 
You can find the information about th 
e procedure and conditions of parcels keeping in the nearest office. 
Thank you for using our services. 
DHL Global 








Edit your subscript 
ion | Unsubscribe 





, error in content, read, 2017-07-08 08:24:20, 2017-07-08 08:24:20)), 2017- 
07-08 08:24:20, 2017-07-08 08:24:20)), 2017-07-08 08:24:21, 2017-07-08 08:2 
4:21)) 



[PDOException] 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xA0|\xA0 Up. 
..' for column 'errormsg' at row 1
```

If I directly insert the same content into table from phpmyadmin it is accepting without any errors then why not from laravel.

Comment: change the collation to utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: @Exprator sorry my mistake mysql version is 5.7.18 not 5.0

Answer (score 7):

My problem was that I use `substr()` instead of `mb_substr()`. My collation was `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: crazy..this solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: This solution saved my day. I followed all above answers but none of them helped except using mb_substr() instead of substr()